# Print output in vertical format for bash with echo

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, solaris

I have 3 variables defined and using echo to display the output. But the output displays in single line, expected output is sideby side.

```
a=$(ps -ef | grep java) 
b=$(ps -ef | grep http)  
c=$(ps -ef | grep php)
echo $a $b $c
```

Output :

> java1 java2 java3 java4 http1 http2 http3 http4 php1 php2 php3 php4

Expected output

```
 java1 http1 php1
 java2 http2 php2 
 java3 http3 php3  
 java4 http4 php4
```

also used paste as below, but that dint work too. Using solaris OS

> paste <(echo $a) <(echo $b) <(echo $c)

Comment: I don't see how the command `ps -ef | grep java` could possibly result in just `java1 java2 java3 java4`....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `paste` in process substitution you may do something like this:

```
paste <(pgrep java) <(paste <(pgrep http) <(pgrep php))
```

`ps -ef` on most of Unix flavors gives multi column output not just a single column output.

Using `ps -ef` you may be able to do this:

```
paste <(ps -ef | grep -o java) <(paste <(ps -ef | grep -o http) <(ps -ef | grep -o php))
```

Comment: Thanks, I used paste after exporting my command output to files as the direct execution with the command was not working. I tried something like `echo $a > a.txt
echo $b > b.txt
echo $c > c.txt
cat a.txt | tr " " "\n" > d
cat b.txt | tr " " "\n" > e
cat c.txt | tr " " "\n" > f
paste  d e f
`

Answer (score 2):

Some thing like this may help

```
#!/bin/bash

a='java1 java2 java3 java4'
b='http1 http2 http3 http4'
c='php1  php2  php3  php4'
a=($a)
b=($b)
c=($c)

for i in ${!a[@]}; {
    echo ${a[$i]} ${b[$i]} ${c[$i]}
}
```

Usage

```
$ ./test 
java1 http1 php1
java2 http2 php2
java3 http3 php3
java4 http4 php4
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
for s in $a $b $c
do
    echo $s
done
```

And if you don't need the variables later on, I would have simply written

```
for w in java http php
do
    ps -ef | grep -F -- "$w"
done
```